# React Native Photo Upload

Tags: react-native, photo-upload

Hi I'm trying to choose photo from the gallery and I'm using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-photo-upload sample to choose photos from the gallery and display the photo in my app. But after I picked an image from my gallery I get this warning, and the photo won't display but I get the response in the console. Can you help me solve this problem? I'm new in react native and I'm still learning, I also viewed some related questions but it didn't help me get rid the warning/error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made this repo based on react-native-photo-upload that actually uploads and serves image through FormData. Have a look:
https://github.com/s-d-le/react-native-redux-photo-upload